# HTML Form - How do I ensure a word I have searched for remains in the search box?

Tags: html

In a form (eg. Search box), like the one at the top right of this page, when I write a word into it and press enter, I can see the search results on the page, but the word I have searched for remains in the box too. Can someone tell me which attribute this is? I can't find one.  I am aware that "placeholder" is for the word 'search' in the box *before* a search is carried out, but how do I ensure the searched word stays in the box *after* the word is searched for and does not disappear? Thank you!

Comment: They're probably grabbing it from the Query string `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=kjkj`

Comment: You get the search-words from, for example, the url, and use the `value` attribute to put it in the inputbox.

Comment: Thanks Jordumus, that might be doable, can you help me with how?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sea

Where `q` is GET request parameter. Can be simply access by server side scripting.

Suppose for PHP It's: `$_GET`

```
echo $_GET['q'];//sea
```

---

You can't do this with simple `HTML`. If you aren't using any serverside scripting you can do this with javascript:

Read this [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: OK, thank you. So basically if I copy the code of a search box to use with different styling on the same page, I can't make sure the searched word stays in the box, because I can't see the PHP? Unless I use Javascript?

Comment: value="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>" inside your input